# How to tell systemd to stop restarting service?

Tags: debian, systemd, services

Is there a possibility to tell systemd to not restart a service? Or force systemd to restart a service maximum 3 times. If after 3 restarts service still needs to be restarted then systemd stops this service. I am trying changing .conf file (with StartLimitBurst option) but still without good results. Is there any other option with which I could do that?

When I see logs. There is something like: Unknown lvalue 'StartLimitBurst' in section 'Unit. Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `systemctl disable dummy.service` and that service won start again when you boot up your machine. If you want to use that service again, you have to `enable` it.

Regarding your "restart 3 times" query, you can see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/736624/systemd-service-automatic-restart-after-startlimitinterval).